# how to output any given table in oracle to csv using sqlplus

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle11g, sqlplus

I want a way of dynamically exporting any given table in oracle 11g to a csv using sql*plus - instead of needing to explicitly hard code the column names each time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059) should get you started. If you switch to SQLcl, you won't have to write code.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have added the caveat - in my instance my company uses a provider based in Germany that administrates the database for us. Although I could use UTL_FILE solution I think it would be difficult to access the file. There has been talk of setting up an SFTP but progress is often frustratingly slow here. That's why writing the csv directly with sqlplus is actually the easier - although maybe also dirtier - option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching stack overflow I could not find an exact answer to this problem - therefore I developed my own solution.

Here is the sql script that I wrote:

```
SET echo off
SET verify off 
SET heading off 
SET pages 50000 
SET feedback off
SET newpage none 
SET termout off
SET linesize 900
SET trimspool on
SET serveroutput on

define table_name = &1
define spool_path = &2
var rc refcursor
column qry new_val capture

SELECT  'select ''"'' || ' || listagg(column_name,' || ''","'' || ') within group (order by column_id) || ' || ''"'' as rec from &table_name' qry 
  FROM user_tab_cols 
 WHERE table_name = '&table_name';



spool &spool_path

SELECT listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id) 
  FROM user_tab_cols 
 WHERE table_name = '&table_name';

BEGIN

FOR v_rec IN (&capture) LOOP

dbms_output.put_line(v_rec.rec);

END LOOP;

END;
/

spool off

EXIT
```

The script requires two parameters - the first parameter is the table name, and the second is the spool path.

Essentially the first query:

```
SELECT  'select ''"'' || ' || listagg(column_name,' || ''","'' || ') within group (order by column_id) || ' || ''"'' as rec from &table_name' qry 
  FROM user_tab_cols
 WHERE table_name = '&table_name';
```

Dynamically creates a new select statement (which loads into the &capture substitution variable) using user_tab_cols and listagg to force each column name onto a single line - this dynamically created select statement will essentially concatenate each column together separated by commas. Later when we spool we loop through the dynamically generated select statement to produce each row of data.

The header is produced by a similar query (the first action once we begin spooling), however for this we can just listagg the column header names together directly.

It is easier to understand by testing the two queries on a table of your choice to see the result!

Answer (score 0):

Please use following syntax.

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
HEAD "<title>Data Extract</title> - <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='application/vnd.ms-excel;'> 
<style type='text/css'>
</style>"
SET ECHO OFF
SPOOL output.xls
select * from &tablename ;
spool off
exit
```

Enter tablename when prompted.

Abhi

Comment: There are a couple of issues with this - it does not produce a .csv file ultimately. It also periodically repeats the column headers.

Comment: Hello Connor - Please add "set heading off" to remove repeating heading. & yes I realized its a code for XLS, but you can save xls as .csv & open in any other editor.

Comment: That's true but that's also an additional step - either requiring me to manually open the file to convert or write a script in VBA or such like

Comment: Hello Connor - I see other answer in post. Good to be part of this question to know alternative & better solution. - Abhi

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SET Colsep option.

```
SET COLSEP "," 
SET PAGES 0
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SPOOL output.csv
select * from HR.employees;
spool off
exit
```

Comment: I may have jumped the gun a bit - I started extracting a table as a test and it appeared to be outputting data in the terminal nicely, however the csv when finished is a mess.

Comment: You could use other Col seperators. like "|"  . If you are opening in Excel, You can do data->text to columns -> delimited by "|".

Comment: I prefer a solution where a clean CSV is produced in a single clean step. I think this is also splitting rows across multiple lines, rather than it being a delimiter issue?